# Inheriting from a class that inherits from a abstract class

Tags: c#, oop

I trying to inherit a class Blah2, but after adding a method it says BlahA doesn't implement that method.

How can I add a method to my new class?

```
public class Blah2 : BlahA
{

}

public class Blah3 : Blah2
{
    public List<int> MyNewMethod()
    {

    }
}
```

Note: BlahA is an abstract class.

Update

```
public abstract class BlahA : IBlah
{

}
```

**Update II - the error**

```
Error   3   'Blah.Components.BlahA' does not contain a definition for 'Blah3' and no extension method 'Blah3' accepting a first argument of type 'Blah.Components.BlahA' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Comment: What method isn't implemented?  What does `BlahA` look like? Does it declare any abstract methods?

Comment: The code you provided isn't enough. That should work. List more code if possible, and the error you're getting.

Comment: What does `BlahA` look like?

Have you declared `BlahA` as abstract?

Comment: Does BlahA implement an interface?

Comment: Please provide the definition for BlahA, otherwise we're just taking stabs in the dark. Thanks!

Comment: BFree, yes it implements an interface.

Comment: Is it building fine after commenting Blah3 class? doensn't look like a problem with Blah3. Any base class need not implement method due to any inheriting child class. Its probably the class/interface BlahA is inheriting from causing this error.

Comment: no, the other class is coming from another library which works fine

Answer (score 3):

Well if it's implementing an interface as you posted in your comments, then the problem is that your BlahA class doesn't satisfy the requirements of the interface. There must be some method in the interface (I'm assuming its the MyNewMethod) that you're not implementing in your abstract BlahA class.

If my assumption is correct, add this to your base class:

`public abstract List<int> MyNewMethod()`;

and in your sub class, add the word override to your method declaration.

Some code:

```
 public interface MyInterface
    {
        void MyMethod();
    }

    public abstract class Base : MyInterface
    {
        public abstract void MyMethod();
    }

    public class SubA : Base 
    {
        public override void MyMethod()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public class SubB : SubA
    {
        public void Foo() { }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrting this code and compiling works fine

```
public abstract class BlahA
    {
    }

    public class Blah2 : BlahA
    {
    }

    public class Blah3 : Blah2
    {
        public List<int> MyList()
        {
            return new List<int>();
        }
    }
```

We will need a bit more of the code that isnt working

EDIT:

from comments you need to implement the method from interface in abstract class.

```
public interface IBlah
    {
        int GetVal();
    }

    public abstract class BlahA : IBlah
    {
        public int GetVal()
        {
            return 1;
        }

    }

    public class Blah2 : BlahA
    {
    }

    public class Blah3 : Blah2
    {
        public List<int> MyList()
        {
            int i = GetVal();
            return new List<int>();
        }
    }
```

Comment: If he doesn't want to implement the interface method in the abstract class, he doesn't have to. He can declare it as abstract. See my code sample.